# How to put arraylist on button onclick method?

Tags: android, button, input, arraylist

I want to put ArrayList on onClick method.
But it tell me i should change arraylist to final(i will put something in there so can't).
how should i put arraylist in it!?

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextView txt1;
    Button btn1;


     ArrayList <String> shop= new ArrayList <String>();
    impshop(shop);

    txt1 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    btn1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Random ran = new Random();
            int choose = ran.nextInt(shop.size());  
            txt1.setText(shop.get(choose));
        }});

}
```

can i    onClick(View v,ArrayList shop)   ?

Comment: usually, eclipse gives you an error, and the quick fix is too make the variable final, which effectively solves the issue.

Comment: I think you can't do it, since the OnClickListener must implement the inherited abstract method onClick(View)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides adding `final` to your `ArrayList`, you may also define it outside `onCreate` method. Doing so does not require you to define `final` modifier.

Though be sure to not use the `ArrayList` to store elements that belong to the Activity's **Context** or elements that might be linked to other contexts of the application, failing to do so might result in big memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Add `final` before

```
ArrayList <String> shop= new ArrayList <String>();
```

so it looks like:

```
final ArrayList <String> shop= new ArrayList <String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextView txt1;
    Button btn1;

    final ArrayList <String> shop= new ArrayList <String>();
    impshop(shop);

    txt1 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    btn1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Random ran = new Random();
        int choose = ran.nextInt(shop.size());  
        txt1.setText(shop.get(choose));
    }});
}
```

or declare your ArrayList as a field